# Discontiguous Addresses in IP Subnets

Tags: ipv4, ip, subnet, eigrp, rip

What are the reasons for using only contiguous addresses in subnets? Will something malfunction if we use dis contiguous IP addresses?

I am aware that RIP and IGRP will auto-summarize which results in confusing/incomplete entries in the routers routing tables. I am just curious if there are any additional reason?

Comment: A subnet won't be discontiguous. A summary of subnets may include some subnets which you don't have, so it may be discontiguous in one sense.

Comment: Just so we know we're understanding you correctly, can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Ok but can you tell me why subnets can't have non continuous values? To re frame the question, what goes wrong if we have discontinuous IPs in a subnet?

Comment: @RonTrunk Ok for example, 88.62.104.0  88.62.112.0 88.62.120.0  88.62.128.0, these IPs ant be sub netted and the reason is that they are not contiguous. My questions is what happens if I subnet them?

Comment: When you say subnet them, do you mean break them into smaller networks?  it's not clear to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: @RonTrunk I'm just trying to understand subnetting. It's mentioned everywhere that subnetting requires contiguous IP addresses but the reason isn't mentioned anywhere.

Comment: "Subnetting" can mean different things depending on what you're reading.  It usually means dividing a network into smaller networks.  In that context, your comment about contiguous networks doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @RonTrunk Yes subnet means dividing. When we subnet a network, we have to make sure that it contains only contiguous addresses right? Why is this so? Correct me if I'm wrong about the contiguity part.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  A network is a group of contiguous addresses.

Comment: Oh then I'm sorry. I'm new to the field and just thought of it that way. Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I got the answer for this. If we include discontinuous IP addresses in a subnet, there is a chance that destination address will not be a part of the network address in the forwarding table. So it may cause a packet to be forwarded to the wrong output port.

Comment: You simply cannot include discontiguous addresses in a network.See [this question](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499) and the excellent answer for why that is not possible.